# Why this jQuery slider disappears when i click the arrow control icon very quickly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have sort of crazy problem in this jquery slider.

when i click the arrow controls slowly it works very well

but when i click any of the arrow controls quickly the whole div section disappears but it still exists in the source code

can you help me out with this issue please ?

full code down here:

```js
// Check testimonials
var leftArrow = $('.testimonials .fa-chevron-left'),
  rightArrow = $('.testimonials .fa-chevron-right');

function checkClients() {
  if ($('.client:first').hasClass('active')) {
    leftArrow.fadeOut();
  } else {
    leftArrow.fadeIn();
  }
  if ($('.client:last').hasClass('active')) {
    rightArrow.fadeOut();
  } else {
    rightArrow.fadeIn();
  }
}

checkClients();

$('.testimonials i').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chevron-right')) {
    $('.testimonials .active').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
      checkClients();
    });
  } else {
    $('.testimonials .active').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').prev('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
      checkClients();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.testimonials {
  background: url('../images/testimonials.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.testimonials .client {
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.testimonials .client img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.testimonials .client p {
  line-height: 2;
  font-style: italic;
}
.testimonials .fa-chevron-right,
.testimonials .fa-chevron-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.testimonials .fa-chevron-right:hover,
.testimonials .fa-chevron-left:hover {
  color: #f7600e;
}
.testimonials .fa-chevron-right {
  right: 0;
}
.testimonials .fa-chevron-left {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonials text-center">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="client active">
        <img src="images/client.jpg" alt="">
        <p>
          These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome!
          <br>Very good service! Highly recommended!
        </p>
        <span>John Smith</span>
      </div>
      <div class="client hidden">
        <img src="images/client.jpg" alt="">
        <p>
          These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome!
          <br>Very good service! Highly recommended!
        </p>
        <span>Wael Assaf</span>
      </div>
      <div class="client hidden">
        <img src="images/client.jpg" alt="">
        <p>
          These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome!
          <br>Very good service! Highly recommended!
        </p>
        <span>Sofya Bedal</span>
      </div>
      <div class="client hidden">
        <img src="images/client.jpg" alt="">
        <p>
          These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome!
          <br>Very good service! Highly recommended!
        </p>
        <span>Tata</span>
      </div>

      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

You've got one extra }); in there I think that may be causing the problem

```
$('.testimonials i').click(function() {


if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chevron-right')) {
    $('.testimonials .active').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
      checkClients();
    });
  } else {
    $('.testimonials .active').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').prev('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
      checkClients();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it's for the main $(function() {   }) .. but thanks anyway